# Getting '${Token[TOKEN.72]} is not valid' error on cdk synth, when assigning ec2.Vpc.cidr value from cfnParameter.valueAsString

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Trying to use the AWS CDK CfnParameter to parameter-ise the cidr value of ec2.Vpc. The intent is to re-use the stack for VPC creation with the CIDR for the VPC as a "plugabble" value.

"${Token[TOKEN.72]} is not valid" error is generated when the stack is synthesized ($cdk synth ) for the following code snippet:

```js
        // Parameter
        const vpcCidr = new cdk.CfnParameter(this, 'vpcCidr', {
            type: 'String',
            default: "10.0.0.0/16",
            minLength: 10,
            maxLength: 18,
            allowedPattern: '(\\d{1,3})\.(\\d{1,3})\.(\\d{1,3})\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})'
        });

        // VPC Congfiguration
        const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "vpcName", {
            cidr: vpcCidr.valueAsString,
            maxAzs: 2,
            vpnGateway: true, // VPC can accept VPN connections
            subnetConfiguration: [
                {
                    cidrMask: 19,
                    name: "Private",
                    subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE,
                },
                {
                    cidrMask: 20,
                    name: "Public",
                    subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC,
                },
                {
                    cidrMask: 21,
                    name: "Protected",
                    subnetType: SubnetType.ISOLATED,
                },
            ],
        });
```

I have tried passing the cidr block as a static string and it works:

```js
        // VPC Congfiguration
        const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "vpcName", {
            cidr: "10.0.0.0/16",
            maxAzs: 2,
            vpnGateway: true, // VPC can accept VPN connections
            subnetConfiguration: [
                {
                    cidrMask: 19,
                    name: "Private",
                    subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE,
                },
                {
                    cidrMask: 20,
                    name: "Public",
                    subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC,
                },
                {
                    cidrMask: 21,
                    name: "Protected",
                    subnetType: SubnetType.ISOLATED,
                },
            ],
        });
```

Expected: vpcCidr.valueAsString passed to the cidr property of the ec2.Vpc construct should be the same as setting cidr: "cidr ip/netmask", as in the example above.

Actual: ${Token[TOKEN.72]} is not valid.
Looks like the following function in network-util.js is throwing the error

```
    /**
     * Converts a string IPv4 to a number
     *
     * takes an IP Address (e.g. 174.66.173.168) and converts to a number
     * (e.g 2923605416); currently only supports IPv4
     *
     * Uses the formula:
     * (first octet * 256³) + (second octet * 256²) + (third octet * 256) +
     * (fourth octet)
     *
     * @param  {string} the IP address (e.g. 174.66.173.168)
     * @returns {number} the integer value of the IP address (e.g 2923605416)
     */
    static ipToNum(ipAddress) {
        if (!this.validIp(ipAddress)) {
            throw new Error(`${ipAddress} is not valid`);
        }
        return ipAddress
            .split('.')
            .reduce((p, c, i) => p + parseInt(c, 10) * 256 ** (3 - i), 0);
    }
```

Environment:

- AWS CDK CLI Version: 1.3.0

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/assert": "^1.2.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2": "^1.2.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ram": "^1.2.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "^1.2.0"
}
```

- OS: OSX Mojave
- Language: Typescript

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems like the `ipToNum` function needs to do some parsing and math on the CIDR to turn it into a number, so you it has to be a static (know at `synth` time) value. Sorry.